# Android Google Maps automatic positioning with position deviation why

Tags: android, location, maps, deviation

So, dude, I use the automatic positioning of Google map API, I am Chinese Beijing, Spain Barcelona customers to automatically locate the address in the city, I Chinese, also will not have the deviation, but the customer said at the exhibition place, there will be a lot of user location deviation, deviation from the great, I don't think to understand why there is distance, automatic positioning deviation?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGTZ2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwloV.png)

Comment: I totally understand that we need to do our best to understand the different levels of English used on this site, but I cannot work out what this question is about. Sorry.

Comment: Positioning deviation

Comment: I have added a picture